# Present Participle or Past Continuous?

Tags: present-participles

A decade ago, nearly a million and a half elephants were living in Africa.

Does the word'living' act as a present participle or verb of past continous

Please explain it to me.

Answer (score 0):

What you have used is the ***imperfect tense***, or as you call it, *the past continuous*.

It is formed from the simple past of the modal 'to be', and the present participle.

I was running, she was climbing, elephants were living, we were having dinner, you were going to college etc.

The imperfect implies continuity, unlike the past which refers to a snapshot in time.

Comment: in what context would you prefer `were living` to `lived` in the sentence from the original question. I cannot think of any where `lived` would not work and `were living` would be correct.

Comment: 'I was living in London in 1966, when the Beatles were at the height of their fame'. 'They were walking in the park when it started to rain'. The imperfect indicates continuity, whilst the past just provides a snapshot in time. You may well find the English language Learners site helpful.

Comment: Alright, my fault that I didn't formulate my question precisely. I meant a single clause sentence with one subject and one verb. Also, I dare to argue about your first example, and I think `I lived` will be perfectly fine there. And it is because the peak of their fame lasted not just a single moment but a certain period of time, as opposed to the start of the rain, which definitely started in a single moment.

Answer (score 0):

Combinations of the auxiliary verb BE and the *-ing* form of a lexical verb are generally known as *progressive* or *continuous* forms. The tense of the auxiliary is the tense of the whole form. *... were living* is therefore **past progressive/continuous**.

The progressive forms were once labelled as *tenses*, but most modern grammarians, for example Quirk et et al (*A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, 1985.197) and Huddleston & Pullum( *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, 2002.117) consider them to be *aspects*.